# Discord.py узнать id созданного голосового канада

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import datetime
from datetime import date

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print('------')
    

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
@bot.event
async def weekstart(ctx):
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    user = ctx.author
    await ctx.message.delete()
    emb = discord.Embed(title=f'Эвент "выходные": запущен',
                    description='Для того чтобы приянть учатие в нем используйте реакцию ниже',
                    colour=discord.Color.purple())
    ad = discord.Embed(title=f'Эвент "выходные": запущен',
                    description='Через 12 часов будет завершен сбор игроков',
                    colour=discord.Color.green())
    noend = discord.Embed(title=f'Эвент "выходные": сбор игроков завершен',
                    description='Сбор игроков завершён,игровой канал создан',
                    colour=discord.Color.orange())
    adnoend = discord.Embed(title=f'Эвент "выходные": сбор игроков завершен',
                    description='Сбор игроков завершён,игровой канал создан,для завершения эвента воспользуйтесь командой >weekstop',
                    colour=discord.Color.orange())
    message = await ctx.send(embed=emb) 
    mes = await user.send(embed=ad) 
    await message.add_reaction('✅')
    await asyncio.sleep(10) # 24 часов это 86400 секунд
    await message.clear_reaction('✅')
    ev = await ctx.send(embed=noend) 
    ev1 = await user.send(embed=adnoend)
    await guild.create_voice_channel("gaming", overwrites=None, category=None, reason=None)
    #на этом моменте он должен взять id созданного канала(создание канала происходит строчкой выше)
        
    
bot.run('token')
```

Как узнать id созданного канал для дальнейшего использования

Comment: А почему не сделать `channel_id = await guild.create_voice_channel(...`? Судя [по референсу](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_voice_channel) оно возвращает созданный канал.

Comment: @ГеннадийП ,огромное спасибо!